# Rails 4 - set conditional default value in join table on create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I have a data model with three models, `Team` has many `Users` through `Members` (join table). My `Member` model have a `admin` boolean column. When a user creates a new team (signs up), I want to set the `admin` field for that `User` to `true`. I'm not sure what's the best way to do this. I have tried the following:

```
# Team.rb (model for team)

[...]

after_save :set_admin

private

    def set_admin

      self.members.first.admin = true

    end
```

This results in a nil pointer error `(self.members.first == nil)`.

So, what's the correct and Rails way to do what I want? (When a user creates a new team make that user an admin for that team as well.)

**Update**

My model associations looks like this:

```
# Team.rb
has_many :members
has_many :users, through: :members

# Member.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :team

# User.rb
has_many :members
has_many :teams, through: :members
```

Comment: Paste your member and user model code.

Comment: I've added the relevant model code (my associations).

Answer (score 1):

Use `after_add` instead

```
has_many :members, after_add: Proc.new { |u, m| m.first.admin = true; m.save }
```

Comment: Thought it worked. Didn't get any errors. But the admin value doesn't seem to get set at all with this solution, when I try to later check the value, it's nil.

Comment: I seem to get the same result using a proc, the value doesn't get set.

Comment: Do you intend for the new team to be created when the user is created (i.e. when the user "signs up")? Or does the user already exist and sometime later "creates a new team"?